How to specify range of genes in PyGAD for genetic algorithms?
I have an optimization problem with a lot of variables. Let suppose there is just three: car speed (km/h), car weight (tons) and car price ($). Obviously, the range of each variable is different: car speed goes from 0km/h up to 200km/h but the weight shall start around 0.5tons up to 3tons.
I can not find in PyGAD documentation how to specify each "gene" range. There are two reasons I am looking for this answer: the first is that I don't want PyGAD to search for non-sense values (example: 1.000.000km/h or 0.0001ton) and the second is that there are some limitations in my problem that forbid the speed, for example, to exceed 200km/h (despite 201km/h seems reasonable).
How can I do that?
I read the documentation but did not find any parameter that would lead me to the answer. Maybe I have to set all ranges from 0 to 1 and shape the range by hardcode!?

You can try:
gene_space=[
    {'low': 0, 'high': 200},  # First gene: 0 to 200
    {'low': 0.5, 'high': 3} # Second gene: 0.5 to 3
],

